# Flutter Widget Testing: rootBundle.loadString breaks Test

Tags: flutter, tdd, flutter-test

I'm building a Flutter app and I'm trying to implement a Widget test. However, the line

```
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString(jsonFile);
```

in my code seems to break the test. I did some research and I added

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

to my app's and the test's main() methods, but to no luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue? I am also facing same issue, can you please post your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with --

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

instead of

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```